# Join with where clause that filters out specific records, rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am making a sports application with leagues and events, the events contain a `league_id`, the leagues have a `name` and an `country_name`. How can I get all the event with starting date today together with the league name and country.

I tried:

```
League.joins(:events).where(events: {event_start: Time.zone.now..Time.zone.now.end_of_day})
```

But this returns all the leagues that have an event today, when I then try to access the events from that specific league, all events are included and not only the ones that are being plaid today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `Event`s and include relevant `League` to avoid N+1 problem.

```
Event.includes(:league).where(event_start: Time.zone.now..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

Comment: This works, thanks! The problem though is that I can now not iterate in the hierarchical structure that I would like (iterate over leagues, than events) I just wrote the following to solve this:
 `events = Event.includes(:league).where(event_start: Time.zone.now..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
events_hash = {}

events.each do |event|
 events_hash[event.league.group] ||= {}
 events_hash[event.league.group][event.league.name] ||= []
 events_hash[event.league.group][event.league.name] << event
end
events_hash`

Is there any obvious more elegant way to do this? (Sorry for the formatting)

Answer (score 1):

To get all the event with starting date today, I think you need to search between beginning_of_day to end_of_day

```
Event.includes(:league).where(event_start: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

or

```
Event.includes(:league).where("event_start >= ? && event_start <= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```